# How does YouTube determine user's region / location

Tags: youtube, geolocation, youtube-api

My app lists and plays curated YouTube videos using `youtube_ios_player_helper`. Some videos are blocked in certain regions and I can't check all videos before displaying them to every user.

Every time a user tries to play a video that is blocked in their region, I'm informing my server to flag that video for that region. The only problem is that my methods of determining user's region are different from whatever YouTube uses and therefore I want to know what region YouTube thinks my user is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it uses your IP address. It is a fairly rapid an precise way of knowing where you are.

Comment: On a national level, yeah. IP addresses work nicely for this.

Comment: @ceejayoz well even internationally. At least you can tell the country or the ISP which is a sign of the country you are in

Comment: I'm actually building it right now. I guess it will be pretty good but I'm afraid it won't be 100% correct like I want it to be. I hope I'm wrong but data will tell and I'll report back ;)

Comment: Ok let's see what results you get

Comment: @LucaAngioloni That's what I mean (I'm agreeing with ya). It works nicely on a national level. Not as good for state/city-level location, but you can be generally confident that an IP is tied to a country.

Comment: Oh sorry i misunderstood your sentence completely